# "What makes them different?" vs "What is it that makes them different?" Is there any difference between the two questions?

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-structure, idiomatic-language, singular-vs-plural

If we want to find out whether there is any difference between two similar things, I heard the following ways of asking about it (the first being more common):

**"What makes them different"?**

**"What is it that makes them different?"**

At first, both questions seemed same in meaning and but when compared, I think there is a small difference between the two questions.

Although, both questions ask the same thing(s, the second one assumes there is probably 1 thing that is different. And the first question does not care about how many differences there may be in number.

This is what I think, however because English is not my native language, I can't be quite sure.

Am I right in my thinking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, if you want to know about the difference between the two, I suggest adding '*from each other*', as the way you phrased it could also mean '*what sets these things apart from other things?*'

As for the difference between the two, you're right: the second option ("*what is it that makes them different [from each other]*") places emphasis on a single, or the single most important, difference.
But it also asks for a **cause** of the differences more than your first sentence ("*what makes them different*") does.

The intended interpretation of your sentences could ultimately be gleaned from the eventual context, though.